Approximations for a Fibonacci-Like Sequence
I am interested in the following problem:
Given $T_{n}=k$ for some pre-specified $k\in\mathbb{N}$, I wish to construct a sequence of length $n$ that behaves like a reversed Fibonacci sequence, i.e.
$$
T_{i-2}=T_{i}-T_{i-1},\quad T_{i}\in\mathbb{N},\quad i=n,n-1,\ldots,2,\quad
$$
My main interest is for large integers, i.e. $\log(k)\sim 500$.
I implemented a python code, and observed that the terms of the sequence $\{T\}$ appears to be alternating between positive and negative terms. This leads me to question that given $T_{n}=k$, can we choose $T_{n-1}$ such that the terms of the sequence are strictly positive. In theory, I know that $T_{n-1}$ can be approximated to be somewhat $\mathrm{int}(k/\varphi)$ with $\varphi$ being the golden ratio. However, this remains useless upon implementation.
Accordingly, for large $k$, is there a way to obtain some good bounds on $n$, and $T_{n-1}$ so that $T_{i}>0$ for all $i=0:n$ and $T_{n}=k$?

Do the $T_i$ need to be integers?

This should be easier, not harder, the smaller $n$ is (for example $n=1$ is trivial and $n=2$ is not much harder). So the reference to $n$ being minimal is confusing.

The general solution to the linear recurrence
$$
T_0 = a_0, \; T_1 = a_1, \; T_i = T_{i-1}+T_{i-2}\; (i\ge2)
$$
is given by
$$
T_i = F_{i-1}a_0 + F_i a_1
$$
where $F_i$ is the usual Fibonacci sequence (normalized so that $F_0=0$ and $F_1=1$). If $a_0$ and $a_1$ are positive integers, then all of the terms will be positive integers. Therefore it's sufficient to solve the equation
$$
k = F_{n-1}a_0 + F_n a_1
$$
in positive integers $a_0,a_1$. Since $\gcd(F_{i-1},F_i)=1$, there are always integer solutions, which can be found using the extended Euclidean algorithm. Furthermore, one can add $F_n$ to $a_0$ while subtracting $F_{n-1}$ from $a_1$ to find additional solutions, and in particular there is always a solution with $1\le a_0\le F_n$. Consequently, if $k>F_{n-1}F_n$ then there is always a solution with $a_0,a_1$ both positive.

A general sequence $(T_n)_{n=0}^\infty$ satisfying the Fibonacci recurrence with $T_0 = a$ and $T_n = b$ will be given by $T_n = a F_{n-1} + b F_n$. To make sure that $T_0, T_1, \dots, T_{n-1}$ are all positive, it's enough to make sure that $a$ and $b$ are positive, so we must solve $$a F_{n-1} + b F_n = k$$ for $a>0$ and $b>0$.
This becomes harder, not easier, to solve as $n$ increases. It's always true that $\gcd(F_{n-1}, F_n) = 1$, so there are always integer solutions $(a,b)$ no matter what $a$ and $b$ are. We can find them inductively. When $n=1$, $a$ can be anything provided we set $b=k$. If we have $a F_{n-1} + bF_n = k$, then we have $(b-a) F_n + a F_{n+1} = k$  as well. But there is no guarantee that if we keep going like this for large $n$, then $a$ and $b$ will stay positive.
Once we find one solution $(a,b)$, all the other solutions are given by $(a + t F_n, b - t F_{n-1})$ for $t \in \mathbb Z$. So if our initial solution had $a \le 0$, for example, we can try picking the least $t$ for which $a + t F_n > 0$, and if we're lucky, then $b - t F_{n-1}$ will still be positive.
Eventually, this will stop working out. This depends a little bit on your luck with $k$, but the largest $k$ that can be represented using a given $n$ is $k = F_{n-1} + F_n = F_{n+1}$, so past that point there is no hope.
